# Ruby on Rails resources #index is missing a template for request formats: text/html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, resources

while trying to familiarize with using resources for planning routes,
I encountered a weird error:

**No template for interactive request**

*ShoppersController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html*
[image: error message]

Here are the routes mapping
[image: routes created]

**routes.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :shoppers 
end
```

**shoppers_controller.rb**

```rb
class ShoppersController < ApplicationController

  def index 
  end

  def create
    @shopper = Shopper.new
  end

end
```

**shoppers.html.erb**

```html
<h1>Welcome Shoppers</h1>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks for all the feedbacks you share.

Comment: Have you done the fairly obvious step of ensuring that the `app/shoppers/index.html.erb` view exists?

Comment: It seems like the file is called `shoppers` instead of `index`

Comment: ＠max just realized I forgot to create a shopper folder under views..

Comment: @Grzegorz yes changed the name back to `index` and it worked now. Is it because the html file name has to match the action name?

Comment: Yes. Rails will implicitly render a template with the same name as the action. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action

Comment: Convention over configuration. You can use a name that does not match the controller action, but sticking to the convention reduces the amount of code/configuration that has to be done.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yes! CoC rules!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the name of your view is wrong. As the error you're getting says: *'Rails expects an action to render a template with the same name contained in a folder named after its controller'*

So in your case, the structure needs to be:

- app

  - controllers

    - shoppers_controller.rb
  - views

    - shoppers

      - index.html.erb
      - new.html.erb

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with the name of the action in the controller!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
I already had the `index.html.erb` in `app/view/index.html.erb`
but there was still this error:

```
UsersController#index is missing a template for request formats: text/html
```

I found that the issue was with rendering the HTML to JSON.

So finally I changed the method:

```ruby
def index
  @users = User.all
  render json: @users
end
```

and the test to:

```ruby
describe 'Users GET /users#index' do
  it 'checks if response status was correct' do
    get users_path, headers: { 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/json' }

    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
end
```